# Sending signal. PID: 22843 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device. i got this error when opening map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, google-maps-flutter

when im opening map using my current location the sigterm is exiting

android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false

i've added permission in my project

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. it's because I was using both the geolocator and location package in the same project for location fetching